# how to brace initialize vector of custom class in C++?

Tags: c++, constructor, stdvector, list-initialization

Having this simple code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

class Person{
public:
    Person(std::string const& name) : name(name) {}
    std::string const& getName() const {
        return name;
    }
private:
    std::string name;
};

int main(){
//    std::vector<int> ar = {1,2,3};
    std::vector<Person> persons = {"John", "David", "Peter"};
}
```

I am getting error:

```
could not convert ‘{"John", "David", "Peter"}’ from ‘<brace-enclosed initializer list>’ to ‘std::vector<Person>’
```

So why vector of `int`s is enabled to brace-initialize, but custom class with implicit constructor (with `std::string`) cannot? And how to enable it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need more braces:

```cpp
std::vector<Person> persons = {
    {"John"}, {"David"}, {"Peter"}
};
```

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that you are using (C-style) string literals in the initialization list, but the vector holds `std::string`. One way to work around this is to pass `std::string` objects. Here is one way to do it:

```
int main(){
    using namespace std::string_literals;
    std::vector<Person> persons = {"John"s, "David"s, "Peter"s};
}
```

Alternatively, you can use brace initializers for each object, as suggested in another answer:

```
int main(){
    std::vector<Person> persons = {{"John"}, {"David"}, {"Peter"}};
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add another constructor accepting `const char*` to your class and it should work

```
class Person{
public:
    Person(const char* name): Person(std::string(name)) {}
    Person(std::string const& name) : name(name) {}
    std::string const& getName() const {
        return name;
    }
private:
    std::string name;
};
```

Or additional braces, like suggested in another answer.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, it has nothing to do with `explicit`.